# Laravel multiple database connections , access denied error for 2nd mysql connection

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, access-denied

I am getting the below error when running php artisan migrate command from my docker-compose.yml file:

mysql-db     | 2023-07-03T08:31:47.529482Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'feeds_user'@'xxxxx' (using password: YES)
laravel-app  |
laravel-app  |    Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'feeds_user'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)

My database.php file:

```
 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'admin'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => env('DB_DRIVER'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'mysql-db'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'feeds' => [
            'driver' => env('FEEDS_DB_DRIVER'),
            'host' => env('FEEDS_DB_HOST', 'mysql-db'),
            'port' => env('FEEDS_DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('FEEDS_DB_DATABASE','forge'),
            'username' => env('FEEDS_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('FEEDS_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('FEEDS_DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

My .env file:

```
APP_NAME="xxxx"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

#admin
DB_DRIVER=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql-db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="admin"
DB_USERNAME="admin_user"
DB_PASSWORD="xxxxx"

#feeds
FEEDS_DB_DRIVER=mysql
FEEDS_DB_HOST=mysql-db
FEEDS_DB_PORT=3306
FEEDS_DB_DATABASE="feeds"
FEEDS_DB_USERNAME="feeds_user"
FEEDS_DB_PASSWORD="xxxxx"

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=xxx
REDIS_PORT=xxxx
```

My docker-compose.yaml file

```html
version: '3.5'

services:
  laravel-app:
    build:
      context: '.'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        uid: ${UID}
    container_name: laravel-app
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000
      - APACHE_RUN_GROUP=#1000
    #volumes:
     # - .:/var/www/html
     ## we wait for the MySQL container to be up and running
    ## then we run the migration
    ## and finally we start apache
    entrypoint: sh -c "sleep 10 && php /var/www/app/artisan migrate && apache2-foreground"
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - app

  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql-db
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql      
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - mysql-db

networks:
  backend:
    name: backend-network
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

I tried changing hostname to 127.0.0.1 and localhost. But it did not help. Could you please help on this?

Comment: Have you checked if the database is already created and in the same container of the first one (mysql-db)? You can add your docker-compose.yml config here to check if something is missing there

Comment: Hi @F.Igor, yes it was shown than mysql is ready for connections. But feeds db is not created. I have added docker-compose.yml file in the post. Thanks

Comment: If you are using in windows change hostname to `host.docker.internal`

Answer (score 0):

The docker-compose file is only creating the first database based on the environment variables (MYSQL_DATABASE). The migrate command is trying to use a database name, user and password that does not exist yet. To create a second database you have at least these 2 options:

- Use a multi-database provisioning .sql script to create more than one during the MySQL container bootstrap process. Example here https://github.com/abagayev/docker-bootstrap-collection/tree/master/mysql-few-databases

Example `01-databases.sql`:

```
-- create databases
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `admin`;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `feeds`;

-- create users and grants
CREATE USER 'admin_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin_password';
GRANT ALL ON admin.* TO 'admin_user'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'feeds_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'feeds_password';
GRANT ALL ON feeds.* TO 'feeds_user'@'localhost';
```

- Create additional MySQL container using parameters set for the second database and name it `mysql-db2` and use that name as host for the second database.

Example:

```
#additional
mysql-db2:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql-db2
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql      
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=feeds
      - MYSQL_USER= feeds_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxxxx
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - mysql-db2
# end
```

- Finally, edit the .env file to adjust any parameter based on the multi-database configuration you set.

Comment: Thanks @F.Igor. Issue got resolved as per your solution. Thanks much!